# odoo 9 Automatically changing the selection field and radio button field depends on the changed other selection field

Tags: python, xml, odoo

I need a help please.
So I wanted when I change the Internal Category (field name is categ_id) value to 500 final product,

and then the Routes field changes to : 
Manufacture checked, 
Make To Order checked, 
Buy checked

and also the Value of Tracking field is changes as well to: 
By Lots checked

How can I do that? Any suggestion ? Or my is it my question are not clear enough ?
Sorry for asking , I never done this before so yeah kind a confusing.
Here I got the picture the interface and the information about the field as well.

[Routes field name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dQAAt.png)
[Tracking field name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tHaAJ.png)

Please anyone kindly to help me. I am so confused.

Answer (score 2):

You could achieve this by using api onchange in Odoo 9.

```
@api.onchange('categ_id')
def onchange_categ_id(self):
  for record in self:
    # I prefer to check by id, but here I show how to check by string name in case you want it
    if record.categ_id.name == '500 final product':
      # because route_ids is many2many field, 
      # you need special commands to change the value
      # here I use (6, _, ids) to set value. 
      # But before that, you have to get the ids of the routes you want from model stock.location.route 
      # (you could use search method to get the ids)
      record.route_ids = [(6,0, list_of_id)]
      record.tracking = 'lot'
      ...
```

You could refer to [Odoo Doc](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/8.0/reference/orm.html#model-reference) to learn more about O2m and M2m commands

Comment: I still didn't understand on what number should i put in the route_id to fill the many2many field automatically